# Run-time error "1004" with named range value

Tags: vba, excel, range

Trying to return a value of a named range - `first_yr` - which is cell `F1595`. It has this formula

```
=MIN(us_forcst_v2!J9:J14)
```

When I step through the macro, I get a 1004 error at the line:

```
LY1 = Range("last_yr").Value
```

Also, the `FY1` variable is "empty". I even replaced the formula with a value I manually entered and get the same result.

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim us_pop_data As Worksheet
Dim i, FY1, LY1, NumYrs1 As Long
Dim first_yr, last_yr, test As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("us_pop_data").Range("test").ClearContents
With Sheets("us_pop_data").Activate
    'FY1 = Range("first_yr")
    FY1 = Range("f1595").Value
    LY1 = Range("last_yr").Value  'stops here
    NumYrs1 = LY1 - FY1

    For i = 0 To NumYrs1
        Cells(1596, 15 + i) = FY1 + i
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Can anyone assist solving the error?

I made some changes and a bit better as FY1 and LY1 now get values but values are not placed in the region defined by "Cells(1596,15+i)=FY1+1". The msgbox gives the correct value on looping but values are never placed in the range.

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim us_pop_data As Worksheet
Dim i, FY1, LY1, NumYrs1 As Long
Dim frcstcolhdr_t1, first_yr, last_yr, test As Range

Set FY1 = Worksheets("us_pop_data").Range("first_yr")
Set LY1 = Worksheets("us_pop_data").Range("last_yr")
    With Sheets("us_pop_data")
        .Range("frcstcolhdr_t1").ClearContents
        NumYrs1 = LY1 - FY1
        For i = 0 To NumYrs1
            Cells(1596, 15 + i) = FY1 + i
            MsgBox "Value is" & Cells(1596, 15 + i).Value
         Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: When declaring variables you need to specify the data type for each variable, the line `Dim i, FY1, LY1, NumYrs1 As Long` will only declare `NumYrs1` as a `Long`, the other variables will be declared as `Variants`. In order to declare them all as `Longs` you'll need to structure like this: `Dim i as Long, FY1 as Long, LY1 as Long, NumYrs1 As Long`

Comment: Sounds like the range isn't set up or has a #Ref error. Check it in the name manager from the formula menu. Also, check if the range is defined for a sheet or the whole workbook

Comment: Is `first_yr` on the worksheet `us_pop_data` ?

Comment: Your `With` block isn't doing anything. It should start like this: `With Sheets("us_pop_data")` and then each of your `Range` and `Cells` calls should have a full stop in front of them like this: `.Range("f1595").Value`

Comment: You tell us that your named range is `first_yr` but then you try to access `Range("last_yr")` so I guess there is no range `last_yr`? Check your *name manager*

Comment: Jordan: Tried your way; no success; Absinthe: no #ref errors and it is in Name Manager and defined for whole workbook; "first_yr" is on worksheet "us_pop_data"; deleted the With sheets bit to no good; there is a range "last_yr" and it is in Name Manager for workbook.

Comment: I altered code; works except the loop portion doesn't place the value in the cells(1596,15+i).

Comment: I altered code: works except the loop portion doesn't place the value in the range defined by "cells(1596,15+i)". The MsgBox does show the right value on looping but the values never get placed in the cells. Any ideas?